# How to calculate vacuum energy density? Do we need to sum up the zero-point energy of all kinds of fields in the vacuum?

Tags: vacuum

If we are not sure whether the Standard Model has already included all the fields in the nature, then how can we calculate vacuum energy?

Comment: When trying to calculate vacuum energy, not being sure of the right number of fields is one of the smaller problems. The first problem is that even for one field the answer is infinite, and sensible cutoffs still produce an energy density too high by a factor of $10^{120}$.

Comment: So it seems some thing is fundamentally wrong in the Quantum Field Theory? Should physicists resolve this "bug" in the QFT before jumping into the String Theory? Or the String Theory can help QFT solve this problem?

Comment: A subset of physicists have been doing string theory for 50 years. They jumped in a long time ago, and some continue to jump in because they find it promising or interesting.  An idea called supersymmetry, which pervades string theory, can make the vacuum energy be zero, but that’s also the wrong answer! (You could argue it is off by an *infinite* factor.) And unfortunately we don’t see any evidence for supersymmetry.